# hashchange firing popstate

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate

### [Here's what I'm working with](http://jsfiddle.net/u6ZRv/)

Code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.onpopstate = function() { alert('pop'); };
    return false; ">set up window.onpopstate
</a><br>
<a href="#somehash2">change hash</a>
<div onclick="alert(location.href);">show location.href</div>​
```

Why does clicking the `change hash` link fire the popstate, shouldn't it only be fired if I click the `change hash` link then click back?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason `window.onpopstate` fires are not because of a change to the hash.
It's because the history has been changed when you click on the anchor tag.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate :

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active
>   history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was
>   created by a call to history.pushState() or was affected by a call to
>   history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a
>   copy of the history entry's state object.

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic of the quote. E.g. if one programatically pushes a state via `history.pushState()`, the history will be changed as well, but no `'popstate'` event is fired. One could argue, that's because there it's not needed, as it's changed by the programmer. But in contrast the `'popstate'` event is fired when the hash is changed even in the case where this is done  programmatically. (tested with Firefox 104)