# history.replaceState - hashchange not Fired for "Back Button"

Tags: javascript

Scenario:

New web pages are opened, and randomly given hashes.

```
var urlNoHash = location.href;
history.replaceState(null, null, urlNoHash + "#" + Math.random() );

window.addEventListener("hashchange", myFunction());

function myFunction() {
    alert("hashchange");
}
```

hashchange is fired when adding new hashes, but not when navigating back with the browser's "Back Button".

Comment: Try to use [Browser Back Button Detection](http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/) script.

Answer (score 1):

I consider this a browser implementation bug: once you've modified history with  `replaceState`, back button will only trigger [`popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate), but not `hashchange` event.

The good news is that [changing `location.hash` also triggers `popstate` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948510/hashchange-firing-popstate), so you don't have to listen to both events.